# iphone view animation problem

Tags: iphone, caanimation

I'm using following code to animate a view. It basically rotates the view by 225 degrees angle.

```
    [viewToOpen.layer removeAllAnimations];
viewToOpen.hidden = NO;
viewToOpen.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

if (viewToOpen.layer.anchorPoint.x != 0.0f) {
    viewToOpen.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
    viewToOpen.center = CGPointMake(viewToOpen.center.x - viewToOpen.bounds.size.width/2.0f, viewToOpen.center.y);
}

CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
transformAnimation.duration = duration;
transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
CATransform3D endTransform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(225));

transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform];
CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

theGroup.delegate = self;
theGroup.duration = duration;
[theGroup setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:viewToOpen.tag] forKey:@"viewToOpenTag"];
theGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transformAnimation, nil];
theGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[viewToOpen.layer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"flipViewOpen"];
```

But the problem is that, at the end of animation, the view is coming back to original position. I would like to keep the view in same position even after animation completes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're experiencing the same issue as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865099/how-come-my-core-animation-transformation-always-returns-to-its-start-state) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226555/after-animation-view-position-resets).  You either need to set `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeForwards` or set the transform of the layer when the animation has been completed.